# Remove async modifier from the method fetchData

Tags: dart, mobx

Im trying to fetch data from my repository, but im getting a error when I try to call the api, here is my Store:

```
class Locations = _Locations with _$Locations;

abstract class _Locations implements Store {

  ApiClient _apiClient;

  _Locations(ApiClient apiClient){
    _apiClient = apiClient;
  }

  @observable
  List<Location>locations = [];

  @action
  Future<List<Location>> fetchLocations() async{
    locations =  await apiClient.getLocations();
  }

}
```

The error output is..

```
[SEVERE] mobx_codegen|mobx_generator on lib/ui/location/state/locations.dart:
Could not make class "Locations" observable. Changes needed:
  1. Remove async modifier from the method "fetchLocations"
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobX.dart now supports async actions. Just make sure to return a `Future`. It will automatically wrap all the mutations inside an action!

```dart
@observable
ObservableList<Location> locations = [];

@action
Future<void> fetchLocations() async {
  final locations = await _apiClient.getLocations();
  locations.addAll(newLocations); // this will be wrapped inside an action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `runInAction` to mutate the state and a normal async function to fetch the data

```
void fetchLocations async() {
  locationsList =  await apiClient.getLocations();
  runInAction(() => locations = locationsList); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also split your async code from your action code (which only modifies observables):

```dart
  @observable
  ObservableList<Location> locations = [];

  void fetchLocations() async {
    final locations = await _apiClient.getLocations();
    addLocations(locations);
  }

  @action
  void addLocations(List<Location> newLocations) {
    locations.addAll(newLocations);
  }
```

The above will work, even though you don't call the action from your UI.